# PS4 14 Day Trial, Will The Subscription carry on?

Tags: playstation-plus

Basically, I bought a PS4, and it had a 14 day trial. So I tried activating it, but it asks my for my credit card details. OK. So I entered them. Now I just got to activate the trial, and my question is, after I activate it, then after 14 days the trial expires, will it start to take off my money straight away automatically , or will I need to subscribe?

Comment: There should be an option somewhere, that asks you if you want your PS+ subscription to be automatically renewed. I believe the option is enabled by default. If you want to be completely safe, just remove your credit card info from your PS4. This will *not* cancel your current subscription, and unless you try to redeem another trial period (which I don't think is possible, after you've already been PS+ member once), you won't need to enter your credit card information for PS+. At least, if you buy a PS+ prepaid card, you don't need to enter any credit card information; I didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What matters here is whether Auto Renew is on or not; to check auto renew, go to Settings > PSN > Account Information > Services List > Playstation Plus. Here you should see a list with the PS+ activation record. Select that one that says "subscription" on the right, it should list your start/ending/next renewal date for the subscription. There's a big Cancel Automatic Renewal button, select that to turn off auto renew (if you want to). If no Next Renewal Date is listed then it shouldn't renew.

Comment: If it turns out auto-renewal is on or off let me know and I'll add that info to the answer (or edit it in yourself); I know for a fact paid subscriptions automatically add Auto Renew, including PS+ 1 year cards.